# Rust : insert uint in hashmap reference

Tags: rust, reference, hashmap, borrowing

I am new to Rust and I have this error at compilation time but I don't get it

```
error[E0614]: type `Option<u32>` cannot be dereferenced
 --> src/main.rs:9:5
  |
9 |     *mymap.insert("hello world", 0);
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Here is my code simplified to reproduce the issue:

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn main() {
    let mymap: HashMap<&str, u32> = HashMap::new();
    f(&mymap)
}

fn f(mymap: &HashMap<&str, u32>) {
    *mymap.insert("hello world", 0);
}
```

Also the following does not work either

```rust
*mymap.insert("hello world", &0);
```

I don't find the root cause of my problem by googling it, I think I don't have the words. It looks like some borrowing issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're actually not dereferencing `mymap`, you're actually dereferencing the result of [`insert()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html#method.insert), because [dereferencing (i.e. `*`) have a weaker precedence than a method call](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions.html#expression-precedence).

So it complains about dereferencing an `Option<u32>` because that's what [`insert()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html#method.insert) returns. If you actually wanted to dereference `mymap` you'd have to write `(*mymap).insert("hello world", 0);`. However, that is not needed in Rust.

If you remove the `*` then you will get a second problem, which is that you're attempting to mutate `mymap`, which is an immutable reference. So to be able to insert, i.e. mutate `mymap` in `f`, you need to pass it a mutable reference, i.e. `mymap: &mut HashMap<&str, u32>`.

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn main() {
    let mut mymap: HashMap<&str, u32> = HashMap::new();
    f(&mut mymap)
}

fn f(mymap: &mut HashMap<&str, u32>) {
    mymap.insert("hello world", 0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to dereference references on method calls, Rust will automatically do that for you. Also, you need to pass a mutable reference of `mymap` so you can actually perform the `insert`. Fixed example:

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn main() {
    let mut mymap: HashMap<&str, u32> = HashMap::new();
    f(&mut mymap)
}

fn f(mymap: &mut HashMap<&str, u32>) {
    mymap.insert("hello world", 0);
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=11b7522c97066ef361c746cb78ae58be)

Comment: Thank you also for the explaination and the playground ;)